# ASP load jquery function within IF

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a page with a few hidden divs that are shown with jquery function:     **changeDisplayDiv('#Hello');**

within the divs are links that send parameters to the controller, if the controller does return results it will change the bool **hasresult** to true.

And if there are Results I want a specific Div to be shown, something like this

```
     if(hasREsult)
      {
       changeDisplayDiv('#Jobs');//Jquery function I want to call
      }
```

Keep in mind that when the controller returns results the page reloads, the default div to be shown is **changeDisplayDiv('#Hello');**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if(hasREsult)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"id","cchangeDisplayDiv('#Jobs')",true);
}
```